# Blur node in blender 4.0

Tags: node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes, blur

I cant find a blur node in blender 4.0 as describted in the online manual. I want to blur a texture for using it to go into the bump node. I tried to find one with shift+a and in the menu, but i find nothing.
thanks

Comment: There is a blur node in the compositor, but not in the shader editor. You can simulate a blur using noise textures plugged in the vector input of your texture to blur.

Comment: Compositor - [Blur node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/compositing/types/filter/blur/blur.html)
... Geometry Nodes - [Blur Attribute node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/blur_attribute.html)